# Form object has no attribute 'save_m2m' django

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views, django-class-based-views

I have some trouble with form in views, i created CBV CreateView. So it working good and it saves the form but i have error 'ProductForm' object has no attribute 'save_m2m, if i don`t use form.save_m2m it will not add images to my product, but will add it to media.

So here we have model.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Продукт'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Продукты'

    shop = models.ForeignKey(Shop, verbose_name='Название магазина')
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, verbose_name='Название категории')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Название товара')
    slug = models.SlugField(_("Название на транслите"), max_length=50, unique=True, blank=True, null=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Цена', decimal_places=0, max_digits=10)
    sell_count = models.PositiveIntegerField(_("Количество продаж"), default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    discount = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Скидка')
    currency = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=255, verbose_name='Валюта', default='сом')
    quantity = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Количество', default=0)
    delivery_type = models.CharField(verbose_name='Вид доставки', choices=DELIVERY_TYPES, default='self',
                                     max_length=255)
    delivery_cost = models.FloatField(verbose_name='Стоимость доставки', default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    # settings = models.ManyToManyField('ProductSettings', verbose_name='Характеристика')
    availability = models.CharField(_("Наличие"), max_length=100, choices=AVAILABILITY_TYPES, default='available')
    published = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    short_description = models.TextField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True,
                                         verbose_name='Короткое описание товара до 300 символов')
    long_description = RichTextUploadingField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Полное описание')
    images = models.ManyToManyField('Media', verbose_name='Изображения продукта', blank=True)
    objects = ProductPublishedManager()



class Media(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Изображение"
        verbose_name_plural = "Изображения"

    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images')
```

Here i have forms.py

```
class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        exclude = ['slug', 'objects', 'sell_count']

    removed_images = forms.CharField(required=False)
    uploaded_images = forms.CharField(required=False)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs['initial']['user']
        super(ProductForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['shop'].queryset = Shop.objects.filter(user__in=[self.user.id])
        for field in iter(self.fields):
            self.fields[field].widget.attrs.update({
                'class': 'form-control'
            })
```

And here is views.py

```
class ProductCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, AddProductMixin, CreateView):
    form_class = ProductForm
    template_name = 'product/product_form.html'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('shops:detail', args=(self.object.shop.slug,))

    def get_initial(self):
        return {'shop': Shop.objects.get(slug=self.kwargs['slug']),
                'user': self.request.user
                }

    def form_valid(self, form, **kwargs):
        product = form.instance
        product.slug = slugify(form.instance.title)
        product.shop = Shop.objects.get(slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
        form.save()
        if form.cleaned_data['uploaded_images']:
            if ',' in form.cleaned_data['uploaded_images']:
                for item in form.cleaned_data['uploaded_images'].split(','):
                    try:
                        media = Media.objects.get(id=int(item))
                        product.images.add(media)
                    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
                        pass
            else:
                try:
                    media = Media.objects.get(id=int(form.cleaned_data['uploaded_images']))
                    product.images.add(media)
                except ObjectDoesNotExist:
                    print('error')
        form.save_m2m()
        if form.cleaned_data['removed_images']:
            for item in form.cleaned_data['removed_images'].split(','):
                try:
                    media = Media.objects.get(id=int(item))
                    image_path = MEDIA_ROOT + '/' + media.image.name
                    os.remove(image_path)
                    media.delete()
                except ObjectDoesNotExist:
                    pass

        return super(ProductCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Comment: I haven't seen `commit=False` in your code. Django only add save_m2m attribute when form.save(commit=False) called...

Comment: o sorry, if i use form.save(commit=False), its give this exeption "object needs to have a value for field "product" before this many-to-many relationship can be used." may be i must use form.save(commit=False) in another place, but i dont know where i must use this function.

Comment: yes.. do `obj = form.save(commit=False)` then do `obj.save()` then `form.save_m2m()`

Comment: It's just the guess. But docs mentioning something about `save_m2m() is only required if you use save(commit=False)` When you use a simple save() on a form, all data – including many-to-many data – is saved without the need for any additional method calls.

Comment: Yeah! Docs have, you right, but i don`t know why it is not saving all data – including many-to-many data, ok i will try save object.

Comment: So it's not worked?

Comment: No, i have product.images.add(media) because of this i have already exeption "object needs to have a value for field "product" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.")))

Answer (score 4):

Try it like this

```
form.save(commit=False)
form.save_m2m()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try editing your view like this,

```
def form_valid(self, form, **kwargs):
    product = form.save(commit=False)
    product.slug = slugify(form.instance.title)
    product.shop = Shop.objects.get(slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
    product.save()
    if form.cleaned_data['uploaded_images']:
        if ',' in form.cleaned_data['uploaded_images']:
            for item in form.cleaned_data['uploaded_images'].split(','):
                try:
                    media = Media.objects.get(id=int(item))
                    product.images.add(media)
                except ObjectDoesNotExist:
                    pass
        else:
            try:
                media = Media.objects.get(id=int(form.cleaned_data['uploaded_images']))
                product.images.add(media)
            except ObjectDoesNotExist:
    # **Edited here**..
    product.save_m2m()
    if form.cleaned_data['removed_images']:
        for item in form.cleaned_data['removed_images'].split(','):
            try:
                media = Media.objects.get(id=int(item))
                image_path = MEDIA_ROOT + '/' + media.image.name
                os.remove(image_path)
                media.delete()
            except ObjectDoesNotExist:
                pass

    return super(ProductCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Comment: i, try edited code, it didn`t add media images to product, no error. But when i add form.save_m2m() it adds images to product. But exeption is ProductForm is object has no attribute 'save_m2m' django

Comment: i thing its a bug of django)

Comment: for form.save_m2m to work you need to do form.save(commit=False), that may be the problem.... edited the code

Comment: what's the exception?

Comment: i solved it, just rewrite model. For class Media added product varialble with many to many field and rewrited view in product.images.add(media) to product.media_set.add(media)

Answer (score 0):

I've rewrote my model with adding new variable to Media. And in view I've changed from

```
product.images.add(media)
```

to

```
product.media_set.add(media)
```

and My model

```
class Media(models.Model):
class Meta:
    verbose_name = "Изображение"
    verbose_name_plural = "Изображения"

image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images')
products = models.ManyToManyField(Product)

def __str__(self):
    return self.image.url
```

in class Product I deleted var images